# How to tie a GitHub account to a legal entity?

Tags: github

I have been told that in order to tie code ownership to a business (my company), I need to upload it to a GitHub account registered to that business's legal entity.

Can you please instruct me on how to do that?

Is it enough to create an account with a name similar to the name of the legal entity in order to be able to claim organizational ownership in court? Or there's a way to actually register the account to a corporation?

For context, I don't have a GitHub account of any kind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an organization: https://github.com/organizations/plan
When you select a plan, it will ask you whether the organization belongs to a person or a business / organization.

However, as always, you might want to run whatever concerns you have through a lawyer.